# Mesibo Android App how to remove Mesibo word from the Video Call Screen

Tags: android-studio, mesibo

I am trying to use this [Mesibo Open Source Messenger App For Android - Real-time Messaging, Voice and Video Calls](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android/)
I have download their [git repo](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android/) and have successfully tried it on Device.
Now when i am making a Video Call it says on top "**Mesibo Video Call**". I would like it to say only "**Video Call**".

I was wondering if here someone can help me out on this?

The closest that i could get into is this file  [MesiboListeners.java (line#259)](https://github.com/mesibo/messenger-app-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/mesibo/messenger/MesiboListeners.java#L259)

I've also gone through all the XML files for a string match, but nothing there.

Upon contacting their Technical Support, they only sent me this clue:

> Please send use MesiboCallConfig to change it to the text of your
>   choice. Please refer to the sample code for an example.

I have looked into their [documentation](https://mesibo.com/documentation/) and a [comprehensive tutorial](https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/open-source-whatsapp-clone/) but couldn't figure this out. I am new to Android but I've been doing php programming since many years.

Any help in this regard? Thank you.